# Regex match defined length number broken up by spaces/hyphens

Tags: regex, match

I would like to match all alphanumeric strings `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` with length of `{4,34}`, however they may be randomly broken up by spaces or hyphens. The length is the quantity of alphanumeric digits, not hyphens or spaces.

For example, `AA99-A3-2134-22-5` would fit this expression, as the quantity of alphanumeric characters is `>4` and `<34`. If this is possible in regex please help me out, I have tried grouping but am not too familiar with regex in the first place.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with:

```
^(?:-?[a-zA-Z0-9]){4,34}-?$
```